# String connection issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css, string, laravel

Have anyone can help me to debug this function?

```
 for (var i = 0; i < NumOfJData; i++) {
                        $('#list').append("<tr>"+
                        "<td>"+response[i]["s_id"]+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+response[i]["name"]+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+response[i]["email"]+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+response[i]["USN"]+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+response[i]["phone"]+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+response[i]["address"]+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+response[i]["Department"]+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+response[i]["semester"]+"</td>"+
                        "<td><a class='btn btn-info' href='{{url('editStudent'/"+response[i]['s_id']+")}}'>edit</a></td>"+
                        "</tr>"
                        );
                     }
```

Have anything wrong in this line?

```
"<td><a class='btn btn-info' href='{{url('editStudent'/"+response[i]['s_id']+")}}'>edit</a></td>"
```

message from browser

> "A non-numeric value encountered (View:
>   D:\XAMPP\htdocs\YangMing567\resources\views\management\st_manage.blade.php)"

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate strings using `+` operator in PHP. You have to [use `.`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) instead.

`+` is reserved for numeric values and so you get the error.

Comment: "<td>"+response[i]["semester"]+"</td>"+
       "<td><a class='btn btn-info' href='{{url('editStudent'/".response[i]['s_id'].")}}'>edit</a></td>"+
      "</tr>"

i change `+` to the `.` , but it still show...
`"A non-numeric value encountered (View: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\YangMing567\resources\views\management\st_manage.blade.php)"`

Comment: I think the reason to cause this issue is `response[i]['s_id']`.    `response[i]['s_id']` is a javascript language. therefore, It can not put in the php sentence. Do you have any idea? @devk

Answer (score 0):

In **PHP** you cannot concatenate Strings with `+` operator. Use `.` operator.

In **PHP 7.1**, a Warning will be emitted if a non-numeric value is encountered.

> New E_WARNING and E_NOTICE errors have been introduced when invalid
>   strings are coerced using operators expecting numbers (+ - * / ** %
>   | & ^) or their assignment equivalents.

Check this link for more details.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.other-changes.php